# How to make some rows of a Silverlight DataGrid readonly?

Tags: silverlight

I have Silverlight `DataGrid`, I want to make some rows enable/editable and some disable or read only.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set entire rows to readonly in a `DataGrid`. You can however set the control containing your datavalue to readonly; just bind the `ReadOnly` property to your rowvalue's readonly property.